How can I selectively alter padding between a figure and a section
I'm writing a short article, and it appears that figures that occur within a section are correctly padded, and new sections occurring directly after text are correctly padded. However, it looks like if a new section occurs directly after a figure, the padding is additive resulting in a large space.
Is it possible to overwrite this? For example, maybe if two mechanisms try to add padding, in the same place, only the larger one should be counted.
Thank you!
A minimal working example is below:
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[ht]
        \centering
        This is a figure which is well-padded, before text
\end{figure}
Here's some filler text
\newpage
This is some filler text
\section{Here's a section which is well-padded, after text}
More filler text
\newpage
\begin{figure}[ht]
        \centering
        This is a figure which is over-padded, before a section
\end{figure}
\section{This section is over-padded}
Filler text.
\end{document}


The is an automatic \intextsep gap after an [h] float and an automatic 3.5ex gap before \section.  About the only way to get rid of it is to add negative \vspace.  You could thow in an \hrule to show each gap separately.

Your example is like trying to compare speed to bacon. You can not do it. You are trying to compare the usual line spacing of the main text with the space to highlight the figures (usually an image with a caption), to make the captions  indistinguishable from the main text and  avoid a ugly document layout with crowded text and figures.   They are not the same spaces, and you should not want to match them.
